# Warning message when using DM.Test to compare forecast accuracy of time series

Tags: r

I've forecasted a time series (5-steps ahead) with two different models and want to assess whether their difference in forecast accuracy is statistically significant. For that I used the Diebold Mariano test in R with DM.test. However, for the 5-step ahead forecast, the DM.test function gives me a warning message and does not output any p-value. Below are data, code and warning message.

Data:

```
library(multDM)

> ts #Actual data of the time series
 [1] 14500  8300 10900 11400  5600 16500 11000 18500 11800 17900 12400  9100 10600
> forecast1
 [1] 11965.53 11918.98 11761.95 11925.01 11751.10 11671.07 11688.99 11790.13 11888.66 11894.13 11850.57 11681.65 11488.70
> forecast2
 [1] 12100 10900 15300 13100 16600 24900 11100 17400  9600 11400  8100 11600 11000
```

Code and warning message:

```
> DM.test(forecast1,forecast2,ts,loss.type="SE",h=5,c=TRUE)

    Diebold-Mariano test

data:  forecast1 and forecast2 and ts
statistic = NaN, forecast horizon = 5, p-value = NA
alternative hypothesis: Forecast f1 and f2 have different accuracy.

Warning message:
In sqrt(gdk/T) : NaNs produced
```

Can anyone explain why this is happening and how to fix it? It works if I use h = 1 or h=13 for instance, and I don't understand why it doesn't work for h=5.

Comment: it is because the with `h = 5`, `gdk <- gammahat(0) + 2 * sum(gdk)` returns `-2.018247e+14` and square root of negative number return `NaN` `sqrt(-1)`. You can check with `h=4` the value is `885835705046` and it works without any `NaN`

Comment: Same for `h=6`. Something looks awry here if the package author didn't add code to test for negative values before attempting to take the square root...

Comment: Any suggestions on how to solve this though if I want to evaluate the forecast accuracy of different models for 5-step ahead forecast? I guess the solution can't be "I'll just use h=4 whenever h=5 doesn't work", right? ;)

Comment: I would contact the package author with a polite enquiry. Send him your data, and ask if your results are expected. You probably should do some more investigations yourself. Reading the references shown in the help page of `DM.test` would be a good start.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is in that the `gdk` returns a negative number and `sqrt` of negative number is `NaN`.  If we add some `print` statements in the function and run, it becomes clear

```
library(multDM)
DM.test1(forecast1,forecast2,ts,loss.type="SE",h=4,c=TRUE)
[1] "gdk : 885835705046.250000"
[1] "gdk/T : 68141208080.480766"
[1] "sqrt(gdk/T): 261038.709927"

    Diebold-Mariano test

data:  forecast1 and forecast2 and ts
statistic = -44.562, forecast horizon = 4, p-value = 1.066e-14
alternative hypothesis: Forecast f1 and f2 have different accuracy.
```

with `h= 13`

```
DM.test1(forecast1,forecast2,ts,loss.type="SE",h=13,c=TRUE)
[1] "gdk : 317749091646343.500000"
[1] "gdk/T : 24442237818949.500000"
[1] "sqrt(gdk/T): 4943909.163703"

    Diebold-Mariano test

data:  forecast1 and forecast2 and ts
statistic = -6.655, forecast horizon = 13, p-value = 2.343e-05
alternative hypothesis: Forecast f1 and f2 have different accuracy.
```

with `h = 5`

```
DM.test1(forecast1,forecast2,ts,loss.type="SE",h=5,c=TRUE)
[1] "gdk : -201824682703276.000000"
[1] "gdk/T : -15524975592559.691406"
[1] "sqrt(gdk/T): NaN"

    Diebold-Mariano test

data:  forecast1 and forecast2 and ts
statistic = NaN, forecast horizon = 5, p-value = NA
alternative hypothesis: Forecast f1 and f2 have different accuracy.

Warning messages:
1: In sqrt(gdk/T) : NaNs produced
2: In sqrt(gdk/T) : NaNs produced
```

-function with print statements

```
 DM.test1 <- function (f1, f2, y, loss.type = "SE", h = 1, c = FALSE, H1 = "same") 
{
    n <- paste(deparse(substitute(f1)), deparse(substitute(f2)), 
        deparse(substitute(y)), sep = " and ")
    n1 <- deparse(substitute(f1))
    n2 <- deparse(substitute(f2))
    e1 <- f1 - y
    e2 <- f2 - y
    if (loss.type == "SE") {
        g1 <- e1^2
        g2 <- e2^2
    }
    if (loss.type == "AE") {
        g1 <- abs(e1)
        g2 <- abs(e2)
    }
    if (loss.type == "SPE") {
        g1 <- ((y - f1)/f1)^2
        g2 <- ((y - f2)/f2)^2
    }
    if (loss.type == "ASE") {
        g1 <- abs(e1[-1])/mean(abs((y - c(NA, y[-length(y)]))[-1]))
        g2 <- abs(e2[-1])/mean(abs((y - c(NA, y[-length(y)]))[-1]))
    }
    if (is.numeric(loss.type)) {
        g1 <- exp(loss.type * e1) - 1 - loss.type * e1
        g2 <- exp(loss.type * e2) - 1 - loss.type * e2
    }
    d <- g1 - g2
    T <- length(d)
    dbar <- mean(d)
    gammahat <- function(k) {
        temp1 <- d - dbar
        temp2 <- rep(NA, abs(k))
        temp2 <- c(temp2, temp1)
        temp2 <- temp2[1:T]
        temp2 <- temp2 - dbar
        temp <- temp1 * temp2
        temp <- temp[(1 + abs(k)):T]
        temp <- sum(temp)/T
        return(temp)
    }
    if (h > 1) {
        gdk <- lapply(seq(from = 1, to = h - 1, by = 1), gammahat)
        gdk <- unlist(gdk)
    }
    else {
        gdk <- 0
    }
    gdk <- gammahat(0) + 2 * sum(gdk)
    print(sprintf("gdk : %f", gdk))
    print(sprintf("gdk/T : %f", gdk/T))

    print(sprintf("sqrt(gdk/T): %f",sqrt(gdk/T) ))




    DM <- dbar/sqrt(gdk/T)
    if (H1 == "same") {
        pval <- 2 * min(pnorm(DM, lower.tail = FALSE), 1 - pnorm(DM, 
            lower.tail = FALSE))
    }
    if (H1 == "less") {
        pval <- pnorm(DM, lower.tail = FALSE)
    }
    if (H1 == "more") {
        pval <- 1 - pnorm(DM, lower.tail = FALSE)
    }
    if (c) {
        DM <- DM * sqrt((T + 1 - 2 * h + h * (h - 1))/T)
        if (H1 == "same") {
            pval <- 2 * min(pt(q = DM, df = T - 1, lower.tail = FALSE), 
                1 - pt(q = DM, df = T - 1, lower.tail = FALSE))
        }
        if (H1 == "less") {
            pval <- pt(q = DM, df = T - 1, lower.tail = FALSE)
        }
        if (H1 == "more") {
            pval <- 1 - pt(q = DM, df = T - 1, lower.tail = FALSE)
        }
    }
    names(DM) <- "statistic"
    names(h) <- "forecast horizon"
    if (H1 == "same") {
        alt <- "Forecast f1 and f2 have different accuracy."
    }
    if (H1 == "less") {
        alt <- "Forecast f1 is less accurate than f2."
    }
    if (H1 == "more") {
        alt <- "Forecast f1 is more accurate than f2."
    }
    ret <- list(DM, h, paste(alt), pval, "Diebold-Mariano test", 
        n)
    names(ret) <- c("statistic", "parameter", "alternative", 
        "p.value", "method", "data.name")
    class(ret) <- "htest"
    return(ret)
}
```

#### data

```
ts <- c(14500, 8300, 10900, 11400, 5600, 16500, 11000, 18500, 11800, 
17900, 12400, 9100, 10600)
forecast1 <- c(11965.53, 11918.98, 11761.95, 11925.01, 11751.1, 11671.07, 
11688.99, 11790.13, 11888.66, 11894.13, 11850.57, 11681.65, 11488.7
)
forecast2 <- c(12100, 10900, 15300, 13100, 16600, 24900, 11100, 17400, 9600, 
11400, 8100, 11600, 11000)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, but I'm not sure this solves my problem. I am using a 5-step ahead forecast. How can I assess if the accuracy of one of the models is significantly better if I can only use h_4 or h=6 but not h=5? This is also not the only of one my time series. I have about 120, and for all of them i'm computing a 5-step ahead forecast. And for some of them, h=5 for dm.test works, and for some, it doesn't. Wondering if there is a better way to measure forecast accuracy significance..

Comment: @JenniferWeingarten your question was `Can anyone explain why this is happening`, I showed why it iis happening, regarding the fix, it is a functiioin from a package.  You may need to contact the package owner because I am not clear about how that algorithm works